# Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider : VS2008

Tags: db2, dataprovider, .net-3.0

I am running an application with Target Framework 3.0 on VS 2008 and getting this error:Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider

I have IBM Data Server Client v9.5.302.513 installed on my system .
My application config has connection string as

```
<add name ="TESTDB" connectionString="Database=ABCD; Server=WXYZ;UID=LMNO;Pwd=PQRS;" providerName="IBM.Data.DB2"/>
```

There are two machine.config files

- At path C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG and
- AT    path C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG

I have put following entries

```
<add name="IBM DB2 .NET Data Provider" invariant="IBM.Data.DB2" description="IBM DB2   Data Provider for .NET Framework 2.0" type="IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Factory, IBM.Data.DB2, Version=9.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208" />

<add name="IBM DB2 .NET Data Provider 9.5.3" invariant="IBM.Data.DB2.9.5.3" description="IBM DB2 Data Provider 9.5.3 for .NET Framework 2.0" type="IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Factory, IBM.Data.DB2.9.5.3, Version=9.5.3.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208" />
```

under `<DbProviderFactories>` tag in both therse files

I can see following assemblies in C:\Windows\assembly

- IBM.Data.DB2           v9.0.0.1
- IBM.Data.DB2           v9.0.0.2
- IBM.Data.DB2.Entity    v9.0.0.3

I have seen other posts releated to similar error for MySql etc. but couldnot solve the problem.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the version number, culture and public key token entries from your add -> type attributes